# Mongoose cannot populate with String as _id

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I created a database on MongoDB setting the _id (string) of the documents myself. Now when I try to find and populate I get this error:

```
error :>>  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "jaguar_warrior" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Unit"

  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"jaguar_warrior"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'jaguar_warrior',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

  valueType: 'string'
```

The part of the model I'm trying to populate is this:

```
unique_unit: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Unit'
    }],
```

On the mongoDB it doesn't allow me to make the _id from string to objectId.

I read online that _id can be string but it seems not to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try thisto convert `string` to `ObjectId`

```js
unique_unit: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Unit'
}],
```

Comment: if I do that, when I fetch it doesn't show the field "unique_unit" at all